# The Domain of a continuous function is an open set

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology

I have started studying the book "Differentiable manifolds; An Introduction" by Brickell & Clark. But I have encountered the following paragraph on page 4.

[image]

Why is the domain of a continuous functions nacessarily an open set?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the author wants to restrict the definition to open sets that is his choice. But continuous function  on sets other than open sets are very much in use in Mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Then by topological definition $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map iff preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ of any open set $U \subset Y$ is open. The whole $Y$ itself is an open set by definition of a topological space. Since $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ we get that $X$ is open for continuous $f$.

**Essense.** In the topological definition of a continuous map $f$ we forget that the domain of $f$ is a subset of some space and treat it as a whole space, and in this space it is indeed an open set.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ and $T$ are topological spaces and the domain of $f:S \to T$ is the set $S$ and $S$ is open.